# How to allow play multiply games from one steam account?

Tags: steam

My bro buy Pubg, and he gives this game for my account and now When I play CS:GO him is cant play Pubg :( Problem: One login = One Game. How to One login = Two other games?

Comment: CS:GO is reasonably cheap; you could buy it for your own account.

Answer (score 4):

As said in the [QA of Steam Sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing?l=english) you can't:

> **Can two users share a library and both play at the same time?** No, a
>   shared library may only be accessed by one user at a time.
>
> **When I authorize a device to lend my library to others, do I limit my
>   own ability to access and play my games?** As the account holder, you
>   may always access and play your games at any time. If you decide to
>   start playing when another user is already playing one of your games,
>   he/she will be given a few minutes to either purchase the game or quit
>   playing.

Answer (score -2):

It's only possible to play a purchased game with a different account, not one game play with two accounts at the same time.

Share the game with family.